# find no results using search form in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a simple search function in my Rails 4 app but it shows no result using the search function.

I've tried several times and find out the use of `"%#{params[:search]}%"` in my controller always returns nothing. If I use plain string like `"example"` then it works fine. Is there anything wrong with my code? Thanks!

View

```
<div class="row">
    <%= link_to "new post", new_post_path, :class => "tiny button" %>
    <%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "search" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% @post.each do |post| %>
    <h3 class="post_title">
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        if params[:search]
            @post = Post.where('title LIKE ?', '%#{params[:search]}%')
        else
            @post = Post.all
        end
    end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root to: "posts#index"
end
```

Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use interpolation on String within single quotes `'%#{params[:search]}%'`

Change it to

```
"%#{params[:search]}%"
```

Comment: why using interpolates at all? `Post.where('title LIKE ?', params[:search])`

Comment: The OP has used it to add the `%` symbol, which in this case can also be moved to the first argument.

Comment: @Santosh my bad, didn't noticed % symbol.